# Minimum exact cover of grid with squares; extra cuts

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, integer-programming

This problem appeared in a [challenge](http://cimpress.com/techchallenge/), but since it is now closed it should be OK to ask about it.

The problem (not this question itself, this is just background information) can be visually described like this, borrowing their own image:

[image: cover squares]

I chose to solve it optimally. That's probably (for the decision variant) an NP-complete problem (it's certainly in NP, and it smells like an exact cover, though I haven't proven that a general exact cover problem can be reduced to it), but that's fine, it only has to be fast in practice, not necessarily in the worst case. In the context of this question, I'm not interested in any approximation algorithms, unless they provide cuts.

There is an obvious ILP model: generate all possible squares (a square is possible if it covers only cells of the grid that are present), introduce a binary variable `x_i` for every square indicating whether we use it or not, then

```
minimize sum x_i

subject to:
1) x_i is an integer
2) 0 ≤ x_i ≤ 1
3) for every cell c
       (sum[j | c ϵ square_j] x_j) = 1
```

Constraint 3 says that every cell is covered exactly once. Constraints 1 and 2 make x_i binary. The minimum solution gives an optimum solution to the original problem.

The linear relaxation of this (ie ignoring constraint 1) is half-decent, but it does things like this (this is a 6x6 grid with the top left corner missing):

[image: fractional solution]

Here 13 squares were chosen "half" (giving an objective value of 6.5), of the sizes (so you can find them back easier)

- 1 of 4x4
- 3 of 3x3
- 6 of 2x2
- 3 of 1x1

An optimal solution for this instance has an objective value of 8, such as this one:

[image: integer solution]

The linear relaxation is half-decent, but I'm not completely happy with it. The gap is sometimes over 10%, and that sometimes leads to a very slow integer phase.

That's where the actual question comes in, are there extra constraints that I can add (lazily) as cuts, to improve a fractional solution?

I've tried alternative formulations of the problem to find cuts, for example instead of choosing squares, what if we choose "left upper corners" and "right lower corners", which are then to be matched up to form non-overlapping squares that cover all cells? Then on every "backslash-like diagonal", there must be a matching number of left-upper and right-lower corners. But that doesn't help, because if we choose squares then that condition is always true anyway, also in fractional solutions.

I've also tried some reasoning about overlaps, for example if two squares overlap clearly their sum must not be bigger than 1, and that can be improved by also adding all squares wholly contained in the overlapping region. But that constraint is less powerful than the constraint that all cells be covered exactly once.

I've tried reasoning about the total area (as in, the total covered area must be equal to the number of cells), but that's already guaranteed by the constraint that every cell must be covered once, stating it in terms of the total area only allows more freedom.

I've also tried to do something with square numbers (the area of every square is, well, a square) and differences of square numbers, but that didn't end in anything useful either.

Comment: I disagree with the Too Broad flag, I'm not asking for an efficient way to solve the problem, only specifically for cuts.

Comment: You should be explicit as to what a `cut` is; I take it to be: take (a non-square) one  of the current pieces, cut across from edge to edge, replacing that piece by two smaller ones. (Done when all pieces are square.)

Comment: @greybeard I thought it was common linear programming jargon - some constraint which is violated by the current fractional solution but would not be violated by an integer solution. So adding it cuts off a piece of the polytope where no integer solutions could be found.

Comment: Yes, "cut" is common LP jargon. Would you be open to an answer suggesting a more powerful branching strategy?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat certainly, please post it if you have one

Comment: `linear relaxation` didn't ring that bell loud enough for me.

Comment: I did not pass this one. It came up as an audit in the reviews. I still believe though that there are other networks more appropriate for this question. Algorithms or something related to Linear Programming maybe?

Comment: @Elyasin There are other sites where it would be on-topic, but it's not off-topic here.

Comment: I thought SO is about programming questions. The OP asks about optimizing a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Constraints on the objective function value

Whenever the objective function value is non-integral -- e.g., because you have an odd number of 0.5-weight squares in the fractional solution -- you can add a cut "directly on the objective function" to force it to the next higher integral value: e.g., in your example fractional solution with 13 squares each having a weight of 0.5 for a total objective function value of 6.5, you could add the constraint that the sum of all x_i >= 7.

### More general cuts

This leads to a more general rule that will work whenever you have a fractional solution in which some subset C of cells are "exactly covered" by some subset S of squares having non-integral total weight w.  By "exactly covered", I mean that the squares in S each have nonzero weight and together provide a total weight of 1 for every cell in C, and do not overlap any cells outside of C.  You can find these subsets of cells easily by creating a graph with a vertex for each cell and an edge between two vertices whenever they are (partially) covered by the same square in the fractional solution: each connected component of this graph is a (minimal) such subset.

Given a fractional solution with some exactly covered cell subset C and square subset S as above, let T be the set of all squares that overlap only cells in C (obviously T is a superset of S).  We know that any optimal solution X to the LP subproblem consisting of just the subset C of cells (and the relevant subset T of candidate squares) must have identical total weight to S, since if it didn't this would contradict the optimality of the fractional solution to the original LP: you could just replace S with X and get a better solution.

Now, there are two sets of solutions to the original problem (either of which may be empty): those solutions in which no square covers both a cell in C and a cell outside C, and those solutions in which at least some square does.  We want to forbid solutions *in the first category* that have total weight < RoundUp(w).  Let U be the set of all squares that overlap at least one cell in C and at least one cell outside C.  We can achieve this by adding the constraint

```
Sum_{square_i in T}(x_i) + RoundUp(w) * Sum_{square_j in U}(x_j) >= RoundUp(w)
```

The effect of multiplying the second term on the LHS by RoundUp(w) is that if even a single square that covers both a cell in C and some other cell is included into the solution, the constraint effectively "goes away".  This is needed because S and C tell us nothing about such solutions to the original problem, and therefore we can't afford to rule them out.  Note that the original solution containing the subset of squares S will be forbidden by this constraint, since every square in U must have had weight 0 in this solution.

### No panacea

The second approach is more powerful than the first, since it may happen that, e.g., the graph contains two components, each of which has an odd number of squares, all of which have weight 0.5: this would mean that there are overall an even number of squares, meaning the overall objective function value is integral, preventing the possibility of adding a cut on the objective function.  But even applying these cuts again and again doesn't guarantee that a feasible solution will eventually be found: as a concrete example, any time the grid itself is horizontally and/or vertically symmetrical but can be covered by an asymmetrical set of squares, then it can just as easily be covered by the horizontally and/or vertically flipped version of that set of squares -- and, more annoyingly, by any "affine combination" of these two square sets (i.e., by any combination with weights summing to 1).  In general there could be many equally good feasible solutions, and the cuts I've described here give no way to stop the LP solver from returning a solution that contains a "superposition" of all k of them, with all squares assigned weight 1/k.

**[EDIT 1/7/2015]**

### A bright side!

Although, as I mentioned above, there's no way of getting the LP solver to "isolate" one particular feasible cover from a fractional "superposition" of several symmetric optimal covers, there is good news: In the event that you do get such a superposition, it's actually very easy to recover a single optimal, feasible cover from it.  All you need to do is greedily pick squares with nonzero weight, each time crossing out any squares that overlap the square you just picked.  This is guaranteed to work if the solution is a superposition as I've described, and, just as importantly: *if this procedure works on a fractional solution* (that is, if repeating this greedy step eventually covers all the cells) then the solution you get must be optimal!  (Suppose it wasn't: Let X be the optimal fractional solution returned by the LP solver, let F be the feasible solution you just extracted from it greedily, and let y be the smallest weight of any square in F.  Notice that every square in F contributes at least y to the coverage value of every cell; so, since F is suboptimal by assumption, subtracting y from the weight of every square in F and scaling all other weights in X up by 1/(1-y) will give another (possibly again fractional) solution of lower weight, contradicting the optimality of X.)

It would be very useful to prove that any fractional solution either (i) has some component in the "covering graph" with non-integral total weight, or (ii) consists of such a superposition: this would mean that you could go on applying my "general" cuts until you get a superposition, which you could then solve greedily.  But as it stands, there might be fractional solutions outside these two categories.

Comment: Very nice, it works very well and since this is what I asked for I'm awarding you the bounty.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)  I'd be interested to know if you ever do run into fractional solutions of the purported "third kind" -- that is, affine combinations of non-integral solutions that are not also affine combinations of integral solutions.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure yet, I have some instances I suspect of being in the third category but they're a bit large to check by hand, and I don't fully trust my implementation of the check

Comment: One more thing I just realised: Although the greedy feasible solution extraction algorithm is correct, insofar as if it finds a feasible cover then this cover must be optimal, there's a good chance that it won't be able to complete the cover, even if a feasible cover is lurking somewhere in the fractional solution.  (E.g. a 3x2 grid can be optimally feasibly covered in 2 ways: using a 2x2 block and 2 1x1 blocks, and the same but flipped along the longer axis.  Given a superposition of these, if the greedy algo happens to pick 3 of the 1x1 blocks first, it will fail to cover all cells.) ...

Comment: ...   To guarantee that any lurking feasible cover is always found, you need to look for a [EDITED] minimum-size maxim*al* (not maxim*um*) independent set among the squares having nonzero weight in the fractional solution (imagining these squares to be vertices, with an edge linking squares that overlap).  This is NP-hard, but should be fast unless there are large numbers of superimposed solutions.  Certainly you can enumerate all maximal ISes in O(3^(n/3)) time, which should be doable for n <= 50.

Comment: Ah yes of course, that's a bit annoying though :) so far just solving the end with the normal ILP solver works great so I could just do that..

Answer (score 6):

I used the [branch and price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_price) method to good effect on a similar problem (ITA's [Strawberry Fields](https://web.archive.org/web/20130821070911/http://www.itasoftware.com/careers/puzzle_archive.html); scroll down). Here is [my code](http://www.davideisenstat.com/projects/strawberry_fields-December_2012.tbz), which (lacking comments) is probably only good as a zero-knowledge proof that I know what I'm talking about. It was orders of magnitude faster than a commercial solver (which I won't name).

The key was the branching strategy. Rather than branch directly on the `x_i` variables, which is likely what your solver is doing, branch on a higher-level decision. The one that I used for Strawberry Fields was to decide whether two cells would be covered by the same square. If you target the pairs that the fractional solution is most on the fence about, then the structure of the solution seems to be set fairly quickly.

Unfortunately, I can't offer you advice on how to program this into an existing integer program solver. For Strawberry Fields, I went with custom everything, mostly because I wanted to but in part because I was generating columns on the fly, using cumulative grid row and grid column sums to evaluate rectangles quickly.

Comment: Very interesting, could you offer some insight into why that works so well?

Comment: @harold Disallowing one particular square tended not to move the relaxation value very much.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a search like [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) to find a solution. It is important to note **A*** is like **Greedy** **Best-First-Search** in that it can use a **heuristic** to guide itself. Assuming you have a correct heuristic it will find near optimal (~0.95) solution in reasonable time.

[image]

Example solution uses 18 blocks instead of 19 as shown in example. In addition to **heuristic** you can use some **precomputation** to increase algorithm effectiveness. For example I computed what I call freedom gradient for each location. For example your initial map becomes a stage:

[image]

You can have your own heuristic that can be equally good or even better. I used this just because i found it was trivial. Stage numbers have following meaning: higher the number - more likely it will be in a big box (there are more constraints you can conclude, but it's a start).

The stage value are sum total of 4 cellar automation rules.

[image]

For example **top left**

```
cell(x,y) := min(cell(x,y-1) ?? 0, cell(x-1,y) ?? 0, cell(x-1,y-1) ?? 0) + 1
```

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

---

In addition you can cut computation work required by removing known solutions you got from precomputation and at each stage. In this case state 0:

[image]

Algorithm itself would repeat:

1. Order cells and take highest
2. Order automation rule results and take highest
3. Find trivial cut offs

[image]
[image]

---

If you want to get even faster results for larger grids then one fairly streight forward way would be to extend precomputation to compile templates. After that you can do template reduction.

For example you could have a template (top left part)

```
--+++
+-+++
+++++
```

You can generate it's hash and add it to hashmap/dictionary with value 4 (meaning it will take minimum of 4 rectangles to cover +'s). Then you have 5x3 range with the same hash you know it is a trivial cut off with cost 4.

Reason why this is faster is that comparisons take a lot of time compared to computing a hash that is near constant speed.

---

Alternatively there is a way to hypnotize whether or what kind of solution we are actually looking for. Using Wolfram Mathematica function [FindMinimum](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html) it would look something in the lines of:

```
FindMinimum[{
  a + b + c + d + e + f + g, 
  (a 1^2 + b 2^2 + c 3^2 + d 4^2 + e 5^2 + f 6^2 + g 7^2) == 119 &&
  a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 && d >= 0 && e >= 0 && f >= 0 && g >= 0 &&
  a \[Element] Integers &&
  b \[Element] Integers &&
  c \[Element] Integers &&
  d \[Element] Integers &&
  e \[Element] Integers &&
  f \[Element] Integers &&
  g \[Element] Integers
}, {a,b,c,d,e,f,g}]
```

This is based on assumption that we have 12x12 grid with 119 cells and it would give us an optimal solution with grid size counts used.

Sadly [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) search engine does not interpret this, maybe in future.

Comment: This is interesting, but I don't think it really answers my question

Comment: This is very good, and similar to what I was refering to when I mentioned using heuristics to choose the next cell to remove, and also removing cells with single possible coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic programming: choose a cell (any cell will do), compute all valid squares that cover it (that is, that only cover the current cell and other cells in the grid). For each such square, recursively get the minimum coverage value for the remaining area (grid minus the square), and then choose the minimum value from those (the result is that value + 1). 
To make things faster, try to choose a cell which has the fewest valid covering square in each level of the recursion (thus reducing the number of recursive calls in each level).

Simple really.

Comment: This requires time O(2^n) *and space* for an input containing n grid cells, because you need to compute and store the optimal solution *for every connected subset* of remaining grid cells, so it's probably not viable on inputs with more than about 25 cells.

Comment: Yes, the maximum space is 2^n, but if you use reasonable heuristics (such as choosing cells along the edge of the area), the actual number of partial areas you will need to compute is probably much less then n^2. You can store that in a hash table.

Comment: Let's choose the leftmost, bottommost cell.  Suppose a k\*k square fits there. Then certainly a i\*i square also fits there for all i < k. For any choice of i, consider the leftmost, bottommost cell in the grid that remains after deleting this i\*i square: it will certainly fit a j\*j square, for all j such that i+j <= k. We can continue this process, choosing a square of some known-safe size to delete from the left edge of the grid, until a total height of k squares has been deleted; every such choice produces a *distinct* set of remaining cells whose optimal solution needs to be recorded...

Comment: ... So how many ways can we do this?  The same as the number of ways of dividing a height-k line into any number of (integral-length) parts.  A recurrence for this is f(0) = 1, f(k > 0) = Sum from i = 0 to k-1 of f(i).  It's easily seen that f(k) = 2^(k-1).  So e.g. if a size-10 square fits in the bottom-left cell, then there are 512 different ways of covering *just the left edge of this square* with smaller squares -- obviously there are vastly more subproblems involved, once more squares are included.

Comment: (For example: One of the ways involves covering the left edge of that k\*k square with a stack of k 1\*1 squares.  Now after deleting this stack of cells, we still have room to fit a (k-1)\*(k-1) square there, for another 256 subproblems if k=10...)

Comment: I clearly specified choosing cells with fewest possible covering squares first. That would also be the intuitive way of solving this problem manually - first covering the cells that can only be covered with 1x1 squares, and continuing from there....

Comment: The obligation is on you to show a better bound than O(2^n) -- for instance, by proving that many of the subproblems I listed cannot arise.  This will be difficult: while there are partial solutions (stacks of squares) in my set of subproblems that indeed may not arise with your branching strategy (e.g., any time we have a stack of squares in which the topmost square X is larger than the one below it Y, and in which the remaining height left uncovered from the original k\*k square is larger than the height of Y, your approach would next try to cover some square to the right of Y ...

Comment: ... (or some lower square), while mine will keep trying to cover the leftmost square above X), nevertheless, any way of dividing a height-k line into any number of *nonincreasing* integral-length segments leads to subproblems in which the next cell that I would pick to cover ***is*** a cell that is covered by the fewest possible squares, so the number of ways of doing this gives a valid lower bound for your strategy.  Since these are counted by the partition numbers, which are asymptotically 1/(4sqrt(3)n) \* e^(pi\*sqrt(2n/3)), the number of subproblems grows faster than any polynomial in k.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a constraint that the total area of the squares equals the total area to be covered, in addition to the constraint of no overlaps ? This should be fater than checking the double cover constraint.

Comment: That's already implied by the constraint that every cell be covered by a weight of 1

Comment: Yes, just thought it would be faster to use the overall sum constraint, rather than the "every cell covered by 1" (aka no double coverage) constraint.

Comment: Well it would dramatically reduce the number of constraints to be sure, but it would also increase the integrality gap unless you go back in and add the regular constraints lazily.